# Blackberry - Can't change theme after lwuit was installed

Tags: blackberry, java-me, themes, blackberry-simulator, lwuit

I've used [lwuit](https://lwuit.dev.java.net/) in my j2me application and it works well.

When I've converted .jar file to .cod file and install it on BB emulator, I've faced runtime error 104.

Then I got the blackberry demo and lwuit.jar file included with it and when install it on BB it works well. But after I edit the theme.res file application doesn't open any more.

Please can you help me - how to apply my theme on bb app which using lwuit?

Answer (score 2):

### 3rd party lib error on BlackBerry

Talking about errors on BB, make sure you have preverified lwuit library and properly built project.
See
[LWUIT - RIM BlackBerry Verification Errors](http://lwuit.blogspot.com/2009/01/rim-blackberry-verification-errors.html)
[LWUIT - Building A Project On The BlackBerry](http://lwuit.blogspot.com/2009/11/building-project-on-blackberry.html)
[SO - Handling dependencies in blackberry development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798974/handling-dependencies-in-blackberry-development)

Also, having 104 error, check the reason of it:

> Art said...
>       Here is the tip, which helped me a lot:
>       To identify the class and method which causes the error, you can do the following :
>       Open the emulator of the BlackBerry JDE
>       Load the application
>       Open the application
>       An error screen should appear stating something like this :
>       jvm error 104 uncaught runtime exception
>       Choose from the underlying menu (using the arrow keys) the option "catfail"
>       Now choose the right most point to save a file named "failure.zip" to your disk
>       Extract the files within failure.zip to your disk and open the .bug file
>       There are three interesting values in the .bug file:
>       VM:VECPs
>       (the package)
>       VM:VECCs
>       (the class)
>       VM:VECMm
>       (and the method which causes the error)

### BlackBerry theme and LWUIT

And talking about theme problem, take a look at:
-EventLog file

```
javaloader.exe -u eventlog > eventlog.txt
```

(or go Home Screen and type ALT-LGLG)
-Eclipse console (run app in debug mode)

### LWUIT under BlackBerry

Maybe there are some issues in a demo you downloaded, in a below links you can find alternatives:
[LWUIT Blackberry implementation by thorsten_s](http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?messageID=321694)
[LWUIT Demo on BlackBerry with Eclipse](http://miketeo.net/wp/index.php/2009/02/22/lwuit-demo-on-blackberry-with-eclipse.html)